# JS, HTML, CSS --- getElementById.value. Почему не работает программа?

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте! Я делаю программу "симулятор аукциона" и у меня возникла проблема. У меня есть два параграфа, изображение, заголовок, два инпута и кнопка. Я хочу, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку с помощью `document.getElementById('id').value` записывались в объект `value` двух инпутов и их значения переносились к двум параграфам. Например я ввел `1` в первый инпут и `2` во второй и при нажатии на кнопку к параграфам приписывалось значение введенных мной данных в первом и втором инпуте, то есть `1` и `2`.
Я со всем этим справился на по какой-то причине программа не работает правильно.`Value` не считывает введенные данные. Я пришел к этому выводу вывев на экран с помощью `alert` значение полученных мной данных, которые я ввел и в любом случае я получаю пустой `alert`. То есть `alert` без всякого значения. 
Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться в чем проблема.

```js
var data = {
  name: document.getElementById('name_input').value,
  bid: document.getElementById('bid_current_input').value
}

document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function() {
  alert(data.name)
  document.getElementById('cur_bid').innerHTML = 'Current Bid: ' + data.bid;
  document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = 'Name: ' + data.name;
}
```

```css
h1 {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 200%;
  font-weight: lighter;
  text-align: center;
}

.text {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 120%;
}

.input {
  margin-left: 492px;
}

.input1 {
  margin-left: 492px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Auction</h1>
<p id='cur_bid' class='text'>Current Bid: </p>
<p id='name' class='text'>Name: </p>
<p align="center"><img src="images/jiraffe.jpg" alt="Jiraffe"></p>
<input id='name_input' class='input1'> Name</input><br>
<input id='bid_current_input' class='input'> Bid Current</input><br>
<button id='btn' class='input1'>Bid</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В вашем коде вы когда создаёте объект `data` у вас сразу берутся `name` и `bid`. То есть как они введены при запуске страницы. А вам нужно их брать динамически.

Я отредактировал ваш код, что бы он работал, и сделал `name` и `bid` функциями гетерами.

```js
var data = {
  get name() {
    return document.getElementById('name_input').value
  },
  get bid() {
    return document.getElementById('bid_current_input').value
  }
}

document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function() {
  alert(data.name)
  document.getElementById('cur_bid').innerHTML = 'Current Bid: ' + data.bid;
  document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = 'Name: ' + data.name;
}
```

```css
h1 {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 200%;
  font-weight: lighter;
  text-align: center;
}

.text {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 120%;
}

.input {
  margin-left: 492px;
}

.input1 {
  margin-left: 492px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Auction</h1>
<p id='cur_bid' class='text'>Current Bid: </p>
<p id='name' class='text'>Name: </p>
<p align="center"><img src="images/jiraffe.jpg" alt="Jiraffe"></p>
<input id='name_input' class='input1'> Name</input><br>
<input id='bid_current_input' class='input'> Bid Current</input><br>
<button id='btn' class='input1'>Bid</button>
```

Можно и по другому сделать, определив функции `GetName` и `GetBid` прямо в глобальном пространстве, без общего контейнера `data`.

Answer (score 3):

Все и так работало, просто, когда объект `data` был вне функции, его данные на момент работы функции не изменялись

```js
document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function() {
  var data = {
    name: document.getElementById('name_input').value,
    bid: document.getElementById('bid_current_input').value
  }

  document.getElementById('cur_bid').innerHTML = 'Current Bid: ' + data.bid;
  document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = 'Name: ' + data.name;
}
```

```css
h1 {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 200%;
  font-weight: lighter;
  text-align: center;
}

.text {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 120%;
}

.input {
  margin-left: 492px;
}

.input1 {
  margin-left: 492px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Auction</h1>
<p id='cur_bid' class='text'>Current Bid: </p>
<p id='name' class='text'>Name: </p>
<p align="center"><img src="images/jiraffe.jpg" alt="Jiraffe"></p>
<input id='name_input' class='input1'> Name</input><br>
<input id='bid_current_input' class='input'> Bid Current</input><br>
<button id='btn' class='input1'>Bid</button>
```

Comment: Хорошо ответил!

Comment: Ты тоже....)) кстати...